# ABAddressBook fromOpaque(_:) in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, abaddressbook, xcode8, opaque-pointers

So I've just updated to Xcode 8 and converted my Swift 2.3 code to Swift 3, and I have an error in this line of code that wasn't in Swift 2.3:

```
func populateFrom(_ addressBook:ABAddressBook)
{
    let allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook).takeRetainedValue()
    let nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook)
    for index in 0..<nPeople
    {
       let person:ABRecord = Unmanaged<ABRecord>.fromOpaque(OpaquePointer(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, index))).takeUnretainedValue()
    }
}
```

Now the problem is in line `let person:ABRecord = Unmanaged<ABRecord>.fromOpaque(OpaquePointer(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, index))).takeUnretainedValue()`

Xcode tells me that `'fromOpaque' is unavailable: use 'fromOpaque(_:UnsafeRawPointer)' instead`. But I can't find that function Xcode is telling me to use, I can just find `fromOpaque(value: UnsafeRawPointer)` which is the one I'm currently using.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Unrelated, but if programming in Swift 3, you might want to just use Contacts framework, which is much easier than the old ABAddressBook...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify this a bit, eliminating all of those opaque pointer references, e.g.:

```
func populate(from addressBook: ABAddressBook) {
    let allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook).takeRetainedValue() as [ABRecord]
    for person in allPeople {
        let name = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person).takeRetainedValue()
        print(name)
    }
}
```

---

Or, given that the AddressBook framework was deprecated in iOS 9, you can use the Contacts framework:

```
let store = CNContactStore()
store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { granted, error in
    guard granted else {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    self.populate(from: store)
}
```

And

```
func populate(from store: CNContactStore) {
    let formatter = CNContactFormatter()
    formatter.style = .fullName

    let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: formatter.style)])
    do {
        try store.enumerateContacts(with: request) { contact, stop in
            print(formatter.string(from: contact))
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```